# Ldap and mysql operation in single Transaction using spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ldap

```java
public User createUser(User form) {
    ldapService.createUserInLdap(uid, userpassword, cn); //save entry in ldap server
    return repository.save(user);  //save entry in mysql db
}
```

I'm new to spring boot rest APIs, I'm trying to save a new user entry in LDAP server and if it saved successfully, then create a new user in my MySQL database in a single transaction.

Important case: If an entry is saved in LDAP but returns some error while storing to MySQL, it should roll back.
How can I achieve this as a single transaction?

Comment: Why? Just save the users in LDAP and leave the database for transactions.